# Entity Framework .NET Core 2.0 Query hangs on execution when subquery is executed

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

With a regular version of EF 6.x I was able to do subqueries pretty easy with the following query:

```
var q = from u in db.User
        let actions = from ua in db.UserActions
                      where ua.UserId == u.Id && ua.Approved
                      select ua
        where u.Active
        select new { User = u, Actions = actions.ToList() }

var result = await q.ToListAsync()
```

When I try to execute the same code in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 EntityFramework powered application my application just freezes and never returns the result.

I tried some variations but all of them hangs once sub-query is executed as part of the initial query:

1. sub-query (same as above with some variations)
2. left outer join

Another sub-query variation (also hangs on execution):

```
var q = from u in db.User
        let actions = (from ua in db.UserActions
                      where ua.UserId == u.Id && ua.Approved
                      select ua).ToList()
        where u.Active
        select new { User = u, Actions = actions }
```

Yet another subquery variation (also hangs on execution):

```
var q = from u in db.User
        let actions = db.UserActions.Where(ua => ua.UserId == u.Id && ua.Approved)
        where u.Active
        select new { User = u, Actions = actions.ToList() }
```

Another variation with left outer join (also hangs on execution):

```
var forUserId = "test";
var q = from u in db.User
        join ua in db.UserActions on u.Id equals ua.UserId into actions
        from ua in action.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where u.Active
        select new { User = u, Actions = ua}
```

The following code works but, obviously, subquery execution is deferred and once we try to access to `Action` property it kicks off another query:

```
var q = from u in db.User
        let actions = from ua in db.UserActions
                      where ua.UserId == u.Id && ua.Approved
                      select ua
        where u.Active
        select new { User = u, Actions = actions }

var result = await q.ToListAsync()
foreach (var r in result)
{
     foreach(var a in r.Actions)
     {
          // extra database requests is executed for each result row
          // .. process action.
     }
}
```

How can I execute a subquery and get a list of entities, where each entity assigned list of sub-entities, received using a sub query?

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9128

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from this.But,you can try '.ToList()'.

```
 var q = (from u in db.User
            join ua in db.UserActions on u.Id equals ua.UserId into actions
            from ua in action.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where u.Active
            select new {u,ua}).ToList();
```

Comment: The point of using `ToListAsync` is that you can use it in an `async` method.